# Swift: Dismiss Image View

Tags: ios, input, swift, uiimageview, dismiss

I have an UIImageView in my view controller (set through storyboards) and I was just wondering how I could dismiss it on touch (it is a 'tap to begin' image).

Thanks in advance,

William

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Enable user interaction with image
        self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        // Create a UITapGestureRecognizer
        let gestureRecogniser = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("dismissImageView:"))

        // Add the UITapGestureRecognizer to the image view
        self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecogniser)
    }

    func dismissImageView(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Remove the image view
        self.imageView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```